# Excel Distribute data based on blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an interesting situation but did not get the right formula so far. I have a column that has blank cells. I would need the values to be evenly distributed based on the number of preceding blank cells. In the below table, I am looking to calculate the NEWCOUNT column values based on the MYCOUNT column and blank cells.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear - are you wanting to count only those cells with a `mycount` value? Have you tried `COUNTIF()` or `SUMIF()`?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52174124/edit) your question, adding what the expected outcome would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in B2,

```
=IF(OR(A2="",A1=""),IF(AND(A2<>"", A1=""), A2/(ROW(2:2)-MATCH(1E+99, A$1:A1)), B3),A2)
```

[image]